# How to shorten ODE equations using ancillary functions

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I would like to shorten my ODE equations somehow, becuase the code will become messy otherwise. I have tried using ancillary functions, like fe() here, but this doesn't work. The code below is just an example Any advice is welcomed! Thanks!

```
# Import the required modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Here the parameters
a,b,c,d = 1,1,1,1

def fe(P[0]):
    return d*P[0]

# Define a function which calculates the derivative
def dP_dl(P, l):
    return [P[0]*(a - b*P[1]),
            -P[1]*(c - fe(P[0]) )]


ts = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
P0 = [1.5, 1.0]
Ps = odeint(dP_dl, P0, ts) 
prey = Ps[:,0]
predators = Ps[:,1]


plt.plot(ts, prey, "+", label="Rabbits")
plt.plot(ts, predators, "x", label="Foxes")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.legend();
```

This is what i got from the python console.

> Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 07:29:16) [MSC
>   v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
>   more information.
>
> IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>
> runfile('C:/Users/Matteo S/Desktop/vocaboli tedesco/untitled0.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Matteo S/Desktop/vocaboli tedesco') Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2862, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Matteo S/Desktop/vocaboli tedesco/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Matteo S/Desktop/vocaboli tedesco')
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Matteo S/Desktop/vocaboli tedesco/untitled0.py", line
>   17
>       def fe(P[0]):
>               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: change to `def fe(x): return d*x`

Comment: *"... but this doesn't work."*  When you report a problem, it is much easier for someone to help you if you provide more information than "it doesn't work".  Did you get an error?  If so, include the *complete* error message in the question.  (Don't worry if the traceback (i.e. the Python error message) looks too long to include.  There is useful information in there, so go ahead and copy the whole thing into the question.)  Or did the code produce results that you didn't expect?  If so, show the unexpected results, and explain what you expected.

Comment: Thanks Warren, I am new to the stackoverflow netiquette. I will remember your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions should not know that you are passing the first element of an iterable, he should only know that you are passing a number. On the other hand in the case the function dP_dl is styled to separate the components to make it more readable.

```
# Import the required modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Here the parameters
a,b,c,d = 1,1,1,1

def fe(x): return d*x

# Define a function which calculates the derivative
def dP_dl(P, l):
    x1, x2 = P
    dx1dt = x1*(a-b*x2)
    dx2dt = -x2*(c-fe(x1)) 
    return dx1dt, dx2dt


ts = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
P0 = [1.5, 1.0]
Ps = odeint(dP_dl, P0, ts) 
prey = Ps[:,0]
predators = Ps[:,1]


plt.plot(ts, prey, "+", label="Rabbits")
plt.plot(ts, predators, "x", label="Foxes")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.legend();
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Eylannesc, thanks a lot for the answer and also for the very useful piece of advice about how to style the function dP_dl.